# How did Toneri Otsutsuki move the Moon towards the Earth?

Tags: naruto

We know that Toneri tried to use the Moon to destroy the humans. How did he move the Moon? Did he have any control over attraction and repulsion like the Naraka Path?

Answer (score 1):

He used the tenseigan to move the moon. The tenseigan is formed by a combination of the otsutsuki and hyuga chakra. Toneri was from the otsutsuki clan so he got the tenseigan by implanting Hanabi Hyuga's byakugan. In 'Naruto Last: The Movie' they said that the tenseigan is strong enough to move the moon.

He said that Hamura told his descendants to destroy the Earth if the shinobi works fell apart. So my guess is that the tenseigan is a dojustsu made especially to do that. So maybe it's ability is to move the moon.